# how do I convert an array from a form into a database using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am having some trouble figuring out how to get my array that I got from an input field. so what works and i get my array showing on which ones I have chosen my problem is that when I add the $selagegroup into the sql INSERT it only shows me the last one that is checked and not all that are checked. i am still somewhat new to sql and php so any help would be greatly appreciated here is my HTML and PHP code

```
<label for="agegroup" id="agegroup"> What ages do you interact with?
<input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="ages" id="kids" value="kids"> Ages 0-10
        <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="ages" id="teens" value="teens"> Ages 11-19
        <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="ages" id="twentys" value="twenties"> Ages 20-29
        <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="ages" id="thirtys" value="thirties"> Ages 30-39
        <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="ages" id="fourtys" value="fourties"> Ages 40-49
        <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="ages" id="fiftys" value="fifties"> Ages 50-59
        <input type="checkbox" name="age[]" class="ages" id="sixtyplus" value="sixtyplus"> Ages 60+
</label>
```

here is the php I have used to get the array shown:

```
if (isset($_POST['age']) && $_POST['age'] !== '') {

    $vagegroup = $_POST['age'];

    foreach($_POST['age'] as $selagegroup){
        echo $selagegroup.'<br>';
    }
} else {
    $vagegroup = '';
}
```

I have also tried adding the foreach loop to the sql insert but that just shows "","","", for every field in the checkbox and i dont know what to do any help will be greatly appreciated, Even tho when i just echo the array it works and shows everything that is checked. if someone could explain and help thank you :)

**EDITED :::** I forgot to add this my insert statement overall has like 30 differnt fields as this is a long form but this is how i did for the age group and it only shows the last selected value

```
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO influencers (inf_ages) VALUES ('$selagegroup')";
```

Comment: Where is the **insert query**?

Comment: Have you tried outputting a print_r($_POST, true); ? That will show you exactly hoy the data is being made available for processing

Comment: I added the sql query in @Swellar. if you could help greatly appreciated,

Comment: if i print_r($_POST,true); it will give me the boxes i have checked in a line with no spaces @JavierLarroulet

Comment: can you explain how to do that exactly sorry im still a junior in php and learning this stuff any help would be appreciated @Nipun

Comment: How do you exactly execute that query? You just added the query, but not the execution. Regardless, if you want to insert all values you checked, for each loop of `foreach`, execute the query

Comment: sorry @Swellar, umm so i have for the page validation (where the if statement and the foreach loop is apart of, then i check validation is all good and all the info i wanted is chosen and added.) then i connected to the server with mysqli_connect() and then afterwards i have my $sql insert. i feel like i may be missing something out because i still new to this tho sorry. does that make some sense? is there somewhere i could like post my code or something or more of it so you could see?

Comment: Can you add how did you used `$sql_insert`?

Comment: can you add a foreach loop to the INSERT INTO VALUES (foreach) @Swellar?

Comment: What will you do is when you execute that query, put it inside `foreach`, so that for each iteration, a different `$selagegroup` will be inserted

Comment: $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO influencers (inf_name,inf_email,inf_dob,inf_mobile,inf_location,inf_rider,inf_currentbike,inf_ridestyle,inf_otheract,inf_ages) VALUES ('$vName','$vEmail','$vdob','$vphone','$vlocation','$vTypeinfo','$vcurrentbike','$vridestyle5word','$votherinfl','$selagegroup')"; 

sorry i had to delete some of the info cause it was too long in character count but here is like a smaller simplified version of how i wrote out the $sql_insert i hope this helps @Swellar

Comment: @Swellar could you possibly give a written example or such so i can see what it looks like :D

Comment: The way your query looks suggest that you are planning to put all checked values in a single column, and that would be bad. I suggest creating a separate table for the `$selagegroup`, with the **influencer's id** as foreign key. I would love to answer, but I use `PDO` instead of `mysqli`, so I don't know the syntax used

Comment: As @Swellar pointed, if you want to store all age groups in separate table, you first insert other data to your `influencers` table and get the last inserted id. Then inside the foreach you can perform the query as ` $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO YOUR_NEW_TABLE (inf_id, inf_age) VALUES (LAST_INSERTED_ID, '$selagegroup')";`

Comment: @swellar i got it to work thank you so much :)

Comment: Do add the code that solved the problem as the answer here

Comment: @Swellar, i ended up just putting all of them in the 1 table column cause its not such imporant information thats needed. i created variable in the foreach loop and then used that as inserted variable

Comment: also wasnt too sure on how to do the whole relational database im still reading into that and learning it at the moment also :(

Comment: @Meitie If you want to insert all age groups in a singe column, you can concatenate all of them inside your foreach into a single variable and outside the foreach perform the insert query.

Comment: ooh @nipun that is actually a clever thing i think i will do that :D thanks man :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect an array of responses, you can serialize or json_encode the data before you save it to the database, provided that the db column is at least VARCHAR of a decent length

I also suggest checking that it is an array and confirming you’re retrieving the input you desire (always validate!), then simply pass through one of the aforementioned methods rather than looping to create a string — this takes up more resources than serializing or encoding.

Comment: it is set at a VARCHAR in database with 100 characters length since all my options dont add up to 100, could you elaborate on how i would do the json_encoded to save to the database. I am getting the desired results when i echo and do print_r() it shows me the checked values that i have selected in a line. also could you explain a bit on the validation of the checkboxes cause it is an optional field in the database so they dont have to select one box but can choose them all so if they choose none how would i validate against that ? sorry im still new with this any help is appreciated

Comment: can i see the whole method/class that parses the data and saves it to the database? maybe also the desired results you see, since it's hard for me to put this code somewhere for it to run? regarding validation, you just want to make sure that if they do check stuff, what you get is what you want expect -- forms are easily tampered with, especially if you're not ensuring it's always an array once it gets to you, then insert it into the db -- that easily would cause you problems later